# How to exclude the parent pom dependency inside inherited child dependency for Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Jackson with version 2.3 in the parent pom and in my child pom I require version 2.9, is there any way to exclude the parent pom dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the dependency's version using the dependencyManagement section:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is an example of parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>test-child</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And this is an example of child that overwrite the dependency version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>test-child</artifactId>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This are the dependencies resolved for the child

```
mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< test:test-child >---------------------------
[INFO] Building test-child 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test-child ---
[INFO] test:test-child:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.703 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-23T18:08:48+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this but it didn't work :( still resolving parent pom version while loading.

Comment: Maybe you should post your poms. With a simple test it works as expected:

Comment: Thanks, @gdegani this thing is working fine, I was trying to instantiate the child module class inside parent module through reflection and hence the class loader was loading the parent module version for the dependency class. I guess we can't avoid that other than writing a custom class loader right?

Comment: Classloader... reflection... How are you using maven in your project ? When you ask for help you should provide more details about the question and its context.

Comment: Apologies, for not showing an example pom, however your example is pretty much the same I had and your solution worked for my use-case once I did relocating classes through maven shade plugin. Thanks.

Comment: @gdegani I think you don't need to use dependencyManagement in child pom..we can just directly add our inherited dependency in <dependencies> tag with newer version number.This newer version will overwrite its parent version in child pom.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is a simple replacement with the same `groupId` and `artifactId`, you can simply add the dependency to the child pom. The version number in the child pom will be the one that is effective.

Parent POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.MyProjectName</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-config</artifactId>
    <version>1.00</version>
</dependency>
```

Child POM:
*(a different version, and also exclude the XML parser that comes bundled with the parent)*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.MyProjectName</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-config</artifactId>
    <version>0.99</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```